# Angular interpolation,directive,ngModel does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-editor

Currently i'm trying to customize [Ngx-Editor](https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/components/NgxEditorComponent.html) to add feature like Table in the editor. 
the editor is base on textarea and i create table using `document.createElement()` and insert into textarea using `document.execCommand('insertHTML')`. 
but the problem is i want a popover on the table if click and right-click feature so that a popup can be raise to edit the existing table. 
but using any interpolation or directive in table does not work.

like {{somecontent}} is printed as it is.

so is there any way to create Table with popover and context-menu outside angular context.

i'm using Angular 4.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're adding code to your application post-build.

Ask yourslef : is `{{ someContent }}` valid vanillaJS code ? If you write this in a Javascript file, will it work ?

No. Because this is an Angular syntax, and it's read by the compiler to be translated into vanillaJS.

Furthermore, you should **not manipulate the DOM yourself when using Angular**. The framework is supposed to handle that for you.

If you want a custom component, you have to create one from scratch (or fork an existing one). You can't extend a component on the fly.